# How to undraw plot with Zelle graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, draw, zelle-graphics

This is a code problem for Python 3.5.2 using John Zelle's `graphics.py`:

I have spent a good amount of time looking for the answer here, but just can not figure it out. The function `undraw()` exists just like `getMouse()`. But it seems like it do not work for the `plot()` command, only the `draw()` command. What am I doing wrong? And how can I keep the window open, but erase the previous the plot before the next one is drawn?

pdf documentation for the functions of `graphics`:

http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf

```
win = GraphWin("Plot",500,500) # Creates a window

for m in range(0,j): # Loop for each function
    # Randomizes a color for each function
    color = random.choice( ['red','black','green','yellow','pink','blue'] )
    for h in range(0,t): # Loop for each pair of values "x,y"
        # Find points and plot each point in win
        win.plot(axis[h],points[m][h],color)
    win.getMouse() # Pause before clicking
    win.undraw() # AttributeError: 'GraphWin' object has no attribute 'undraw'
```

Comment: Not enough information ... so +Close for now. Add things like: what language? what lib? what exactly is `win` and where it is defined/declared ?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that `undraw()` is a method of `GraphicsObject`, not `GraphWin`, so `win.undraw()` is simply incorrect.

The second issue is that `plot()` is a low level pixel setting method that does not keep track of what it did at the Zelle Graphics level, unlike objects that are drawn.

However, the underpinning is Tkinter which does keep track of objects that it draws, and GraphWin is a subclass of Canvas, so you can do:

```
win = GraphWin("Plot", 500, 500) # Creates a window

for m in range(j):  # Loop for each function
    color = random.choice(['red', 'black', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue']) # Randomizes a color for each function
    for h in range(t):  # Loop for each pair of values "x, y"
        win.plot(axis[h], points[m][h], color) # Find points and plot each point in win
    win.getMouse()  # Pause before clicking
    win.delete("all")  # Clear out old plot
```

Comment: I think your answer would be clearer if you indicated that the `win.delete("all")` was calling the inherited `Canvas.delete()` method (and passing it the special predefined tag `"all"`). Folks may not realize that `GraphWin` doesn't have its own definition of a method by that name.